# Hibernate entity virtual column error?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, rest

I have defined a virtual column `distanceInKm` in my `Entity` for some distance calculation and giving response to the user along with `distanceInKm` which is a virtual column not a column in my table,and it's working well **(case 1)**.

now am using the same entity for fetching all the values from the table but am getting `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'restaurant0_.distanceInKm' in 'field list'`.**(case 2)**

I came to know the usage of `@Transiant` annotation for virtual columns which is used for calculation.but if am using that the virtual column will not be serialized/added to user response in **(case 1)**.i need to implement both the `API` ie , **Case 1 & Case 2** by using one entity

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "restaurants")
    public class Restaurants implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "restaurant_id")
        private int restaurantId;

        @Column(name = "restaurant_name")
        private String restaurantName;

        @Column(name = "category_id")
        private Integer categoryId;

        @Column(name = "image_url")
        private String imageUrl;

        private Float longitude;

        private Float latitude;

        @Column(name = "contact_name")
        private String contactName;

        @Column(name = "primary_phone")
        private String primaryPhone;

        @Column(name = "secondary_phone")
        private String secondaryPhone;

        private String fax;

        private String address1;

        private String address2;

        /*  Virtual column   */
        @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private String distanceInKm;

}
```

Help is appreciated.

My query for distance comparison,

```
SELECT restaurant_id,restaurant_name,
category_id,image_url,longitude,latitude,
contact_name,primary_phone,secondary_phone,
fax,address1,address2,
((ACOS(SIN(:lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(:lat * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS((:lon-longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) 
AS `distanceInKm` FROM 
`restaurants` HAVING 
`distanceInKm`<=1 
ORDER BY `distanceInKm` ASC
```

My Method

```
public List<Restaurants> getRestaurantsByDistance(FilterRestaurantRequest filterRestaurantRequest) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Float latitude = Float.parseFloat(filterRestaurantRequest.getLatitude());
        Float longitude = Float.parseFloat(filterRestaurantRequest.getLongitude());
        String sql = "SELECT restaurant_id,restaurant_name,category_id,image_url,longitude,latitude,contact_name,primary_phone,secondary_phone,fax,address1,address2,((ACOS(SIN(:lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(:lat * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS((:lon-longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distanceInKm` FROM `restaurants` HAVING `distanceInKm`<=1 ORDER BY `distanceInKm` ASC";
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql).addEntity(Restaurants.class);
        query.setParameter("lat", latitude);
        query.setParameter("lon", longitude);
        List<Restaurants> restaurantses = query.list();
        return restaurantses;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are going to make some calculations, you can express virtual column as a SQL formula or column value in the database. If I understood you @Formula annotation will do what you want. Here is tutorial  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e6481 and this is example http://gokhan.ozar.net/hibernate-derived-properties-formula-annotation/

Comment: I have updated my question with query.pls tell me how can this apply with my query.i have tried `@Formula` annotation earlier but couldn't make it..

Comment: I am sure you have tried this before but could you try also my solution for formula **@Formula("(select ((ACOS(SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) * SIN(r.latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(r.latitude * PI()/180) * COS((longitude-r.longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180/PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) as distanceInKm from restaurants r having (distanceInKm) <= 1 ORDER BY distanceInKm ASC)")
private float distanceInKm;**